# Looping through directories from CSV file

Tags: powershell

I have a working PS script that's used to compare the contents of two directories and report any missing files or files that have different contents. This is what it currently does:

1. Takes two specific directories.
2. Pulls all of the files from each directory (minus any excluded paths/files).
3. Checks to see if any files are missing from one or the other.
4. For each file that is in both directories, it does a hash comparison of that file's contents.
5. Places the results in variables based on files in the source but not the destination and vice-versa, and files that were in both the source and destination but had different contents.

Below is the main chunk of code that does all this. What I need to change/add is the ability to list ONLY the specific paths I want to be compared between the two servers. For example, say I want the following paths to be used for the comparison:

- D:\Files\Stuff
- D:\Files\Contents\Folders\MoreStuff
- D:\Files\Archive

I would want each of those directories compared between their counterpart on the other server. Meaning it would compare the `D:\Files\Stuff` path between `server 1` and `server 2`. It would NOT compare the paths with each other, though. Meaning, I *DON'T* want it to compare `D:\Files\Stuff` with `D:\Files\Archive`, regardless of the server.

What's the best way I can achieve this?

```
$SourceDir = "\\12345-serverP1\D$\Files";
$DestDir = "\\54321-serverP2\D$\Files";

#The excluded array holds all of the specific paths, files, and file types you don't want to be compared.
$ExcludedPaths = @(Import-Csv -LiteralPath 'D:\ExclusionList.csv') |Select-Object -Expand ExcludedPaths;
$ExcludedFiles = @(Import-Csv -LiteralPath 'D:\ExclusionList.csv') |Select-Object -Expand ExcludedFiles;

#Script block which stores the filter for the Where-Object used to exclude chosen paths.
#This script is called with the -FilterScript parameter below.
$Filter = {
    $FullName = $_.FullName
    -not($ExcludedPaths | Where-Object {$FullName -like "$_*";})
}

#Grabs all files from each directory, minus the excluded paths and files, and assigns them to variables based on Source and Destination.
try {$SourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $SourceDir -Exclude $ExcludedFiles -Force -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object -FilterScript $Filter;}
catch {Write-Output  "$(Get-Date) The following Source path was not found: $SourceDir" | Out-File $ErrorLog -Append;}

try {$DestFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $DestDir -Exclude $ExcludedFiles -Force -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object -FilterScript $Filter;}
catch {Write-Output  "$(Get-Date) The following Destination path was not found: $DestDir" | Out-File $ErrorLog -Append;}

#Pulls the name of each file and assigns it to a variable.
$SourceFileNames = $SourceFiles | % { $_.Name };
$DestFileNames = $DestFiles | % { $_.Name };

#Empty variables to be used in the loops below.
$MissingFromDestination = @();
$MissingFromSource = @();
$DifferentFiles = @();
$IdenticalFiles = @();

#Iterates through each file in the Source directory and compares the name against each file in the Destination directory.
#If the file is missing from the Destination, it is added to the MissingFromDestination variable. 
#If the file appears in both directories, it compares the hash of both files. 
#If the hash is the same, it adds it to the IdenticalFiles variable. If the hash is different, it adds the Source file to the DifferentFiles variable.
try {
    foreach ($f in $SourceFiles) {
        if (!$DestFileNames.Contains($f.Name)) {$MissingFromDestination += $f;}
        elseif ($DestFileNames.Contains($f.Name)) {$IdenticalFiles += $f;}
        else {
            $t = $DestFiles | Where { $_.Name -eq $f.Name };
            if ((Get-FileHash $f.FullName).hash -ne (Get-FileHash $t.FullName).hash) {$DifferentFiles += $f;}
        }
    }
}
catch {Write-Output  "$(Get-Date) The Destination variable is null due to an incorrect path." | Out-File $ErrorLog -Append;}

#Iterates through each file in the Destination directory and compares the name against each file in the Source directory.
#If the file is missing from the Source, it is added to the MissingFromSource variable.
try {
    foreach ($f in $DestFiles) {
        if (!$SourceFileNames.Contains($f.Name)) {$MissingFromSource += $f;}
    }
}
catch {Write-Output  "$(Get-Date) The Source variable is null due to an incorrect path." | Out-File $ErrorLog -Append;}
```

Comment: Seems like you could use a tool like `robocopy` and save a lot of effort.

Comment: I agree, robocopy or a diff tool like [winmerge](http://winmerge.org) seem more appropriate. Also PS doesn't require `;` at the end of a line, you can remove them all... unless you're putting two separate commands on a single line.

Comment: I'm sure those are both great, but right now I just have to get this working. Thanks for the info about the semicolon, I didn't realize that!

Comment: Sometimes the fastest way to get something working is not to reinvent the wheel.